# React Router no input file specified

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-router to navigate my page to auth page. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './components/app';
import Authenticate from './components/auth/index';
import Login from './components/auth/login';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="authenticate">
                <IndexRoute component={Login} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Login} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container')
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/authenticate" component={Authenticate}>
                <IndexRoute component={Login} />
                <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>

            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

The problem is every time I navigate to `authenticate/login` it always say `No input file specified.`. But if I navigate to `/` it works properly

Any solution?

Comment: Check if you have imported the Authenticate component properly and also try to change browserHistory to hashHistory.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've update my question with import statement. thanks

Answer (score 8):

Hi I was having the same problem and this is the solution that worked for met.

React-router does not really create real pages. 
So in my case my compiled JS was loaded at my index.html but if you go to /login for example it is not loading your index.php and give a 404.

The error "No input file specified." is usually an Ubuntu Ngnix error.

**Solution**

You can modify your Ngnix config file by adding the following code:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
```

It should be added in the server > location. This is what my config file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yourownurl.com;
    root "/home/vagrant/path/to/your/site";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps some people out.